# next word suggestion api in autocomplete elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, search, autocomplete, autosuggest, elastica

I am implementing auto suggestion in elasticsearch using elastica library.

When users search for **"grinder"**, elasticsearch populates suggestions like "grinder mixer", "grinder machine", "grinder in kitchen".

How we can implement this using elastica library?

Comment: have you figured this out?

Comment: Yes i have solved my issue.

Comment: Can you please share your solution. I'm stuck with the same thing